# How to recover lost partitions in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, gparted

I found some old answers, but I think it is justified to ask this for 18.04. I had Windows 10 + 18.04 as dual boot. I tried to change an empty NTFS drive to ext4 and everything collapsed. I don't know whether it was me or `gparted` a bit too difficult to use. Everything died and the laptop was useless.

I installed Windows 10 in an empty partition and somehow the process brought back most of the drives. I still have an NTFS and ext4 drive to recover. I tried partition recovery wizards on Windows 10. Most of them are pricey.

Is there any tool we can use from an Ubuntu live USB which bring back these 2 or at least the NTFS partition back ? Thanks.

PS : The lost partitions remain untouched under a 176 GB unallocated space.

[image]

Update 1 :

This is where I am now, how to proceed ?

[image]

Comment: @karel , I am not looking to recover data. Some tools showed me that I can recover the partition as they were before. No need to recover data and put it somewhere. I was trying find a tool which will be able to do it, through Ubuntu.

Comment: @user227495 yes, please read the answer of the first duplicate: `testdisk` is your friend!